# HTTP gzip encoding with multipart message

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat, jersey

I am trying to send a `gzip`ed multipart `POST` to a Tomcat server from a Java application using Jersey.  When the multipart request is not compressed, it works perfectly fine.  Other types of compressed POSTS work fine, such as sending a single entity XML.  I (believe) posting compressed data isn't an HTTP standard, but it does seem Tomcat supports it to some degree.

a working uncompressed multipart post:

```
POST /myApp/rest/data HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=Boundary_1_23237284_1331130438482
Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;Version=1;Path=/myApp/
MIME-Version: 1.0
User-Agent: Java/1.6.0_26
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

d3
--Boundary_1_23237284_1331130438482
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="uploadFile.war"; modification-date="Wed, 29 Feb 2012 18:01:38 GMT"; size=25343899; name="file"

{binary data here}
--Boundary_1_25179713_1331128929019
Content-Type: application/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><myXMLEntity>stuff</myXMLEntity>
--Boundary_1_25179713_1331128929019--
```

When I compress it using the Jersey `GZIPContentEncodingFilter()` the following headers are sent, and I get back an HTTP 400 with a description of "incorrect syntax"

```
POST /myApp/rest/data HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/mixed
Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;Version=1;Path=/myApp/
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Java/1.6.0_26
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{binary data here}
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?  Should the `Content-Type` actually read `multipart/x-gzip`?  I notice that when it gets compressed, the boundary text gets left off of the `Content-Type` header - is this also a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this same issue (or something very similar) and tracked it down to the `Content-Type` header missing the `boundary` parameter when using `GZIPContentEncodingFilter`.  I was able to work around it by using [MultiPartMediaTypes.createFormData()](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/contribs/jersey-multipart/com/sun/jersey/multipart/MultiPartMediaTypes.html#createFormData%28%29) when setting the type of the entity I was POSTing from the Jersey client.  Doing so makes sure the `boundary` parameter is set earlier than Jersey would automatically set it, which seems to be too late when using the `GZIPContentEncodingFilter` for compressing the request entity.  There is an equivalent method for `multipart/mixed`.

I don't have an IDE handy but something similar to this:

```
// client is a Jersey Client object
client.resource(uri).entity(multipartFormData, MultiPartMediaTypes.createFormData()).post(ClientResponse.class);
```

All that said, this will still only work if your server is able to handle GZIP compressed requests.

Answer (score -1):

IMO you can't do this that way, because the server and the client need to agree on how to communicate (e.g. zip compression). HTTP is designed as request/response and server can return what the client can support. 
The client sends request to the saying, "Hey server, I need this resource and I support gzip, so you can return gzip if you can". :) 
Imagine a situation that your client sends to the server a few megabytes in gzip, but the server doesn't support this.